# IP address of apps scripts for whitelist

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to build an automatic program that get leads from API to my google sheet.
when im running the program from my pc all works great, but, when im trying to let it run automatic by trigger im getting error that this IP is not whitelisted and the program stop running..
so i just need to know what is the IP address that the trigger running from for whitelist him..
any help please?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_other_database_connections), the list of IP addresses which Apps Script functions can run and make calls from are as follows (there's a lot of them!):

- 8.8.4.0/24
- 8.8.8.0/24
- 8.34.208.0/20
- 8.35.192.0/20
- 23.236.48.0/20
- 23.251.128.0/19
- 34.64.0.0/11
- 34.96.0.0/12
- 34.112.0.0/14
- 34.116.0.0/20
- 34.120.0.0/13
- 34.128.0.0/10
- 35.184.0.0/13
- 35.192.0.0/14
- 35.196.0.0/15
- 35.198.0.0/16
- 35.199.0.0/17
- 35.199.128.0/18
- 35.200.0.0/13
- 35.208.0.0/12
- 35.224.0.0/12
- 35.240.0.0/13
- 64.15.112.0/20
- 64.233.160.0/19
- 66.102.0.0/20
- 66.249.64.0/19
- 70.32.128.0/19
- 72.14.192.0/18
- 74.114.24.0/21
- 74.125.0.0/16
- 104.154.0.0/15
- 104.196.0.0/14
- 104.237.160.0/19
- 107.167.160.0/19
- 107.178.192.0/18
- 108.59.80.0/20
- 108.170.192.0/18
- 108.177.0.0/17
- 130.211.0.0/16
- 136.112.0.0/12
- 142.250.0.0/15
- 146.148.0.0/17
- 162.216.148.0/22
- 162.222.176.0/21
- 172.110.32.0/21
- 172.217.0.0/16
- 172.253.0.0/16
- 173.194.0.0/16
- 173.255.112.0/20
- 192.158.28.0/22
- 192.178.0.0/15
- 193.186.4.0/24
- 199.36.154.0/23
- 199.36.156.0/24
- 199.192.112.0/22
- 199.223.232.0/21
- 207.223.160.0/20
- 208.65.152.0/22
- 208.68.108.0/22
- 208.81.188.0/22
- 208.117.224.0/19
- 209.85.128.0/17
- 216.58.192.0/19
- 216.73.80.0/20
- 216.239.32.0/19
- 2001:4860::/32
- 2404:6800::/32
- 2404:f340::/32
- 2600:1900::/28
- 2606:73c0::/32
- 2607:f8b0::/32
- 2620:11a:a000::/40
- 2620:120:e000::/40
- 2800:3f0::/32
- 2a00:1450::/32
- 2c0f:fb50::/32

You will need to white list *all* of these IP addresses as the requests can be made from any of the IP pools.

Google announces these IP addresses to the internet publically in `txt` format [here](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt) and in `JSON` format [here](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json) if you want to get these dynamically, though be aware that while these are maintained and working at time of writing this answer, there is no guarantee of maintenence in the future.

Additional Resources:

- [Obtain Google IP address ranges - Google Workspace Admin Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322)

Comment: Thanks a lot! i will try to whitelist all those IP's